# How to update a column to match data from another column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to get a query going that would update the parent_id row to reflect the corresponding username that possesses the same member_id as the parent_id.

Below is a representation of the **db_name.members** table, and I want to convert the parent_ids into their corresponding usernames.

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  name  | username | member_id | parent_id |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| Jeff   | Jeff     |       167 | NULL      |
| Asia   | Asia     |       143 | NULL      |
| Bogart | Bogart   |       389 | 167       |
| Greg   | Greg     |       894 | NULL      |
| Hatsy  | Hatsy    |       328 | 167       |
| Super  | Super    |       721 | NULL      |
| Goku   | Goku     |       534 | 894       |
| Banana | Banana   |       520 | NULL      |
| Kyle   | Kyle     |       456 | 520       |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

What it should look like after:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  name  | username | member_id | parent_id |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| Jeff   | Jeff     |       167 | NULL      |
| Asia   | Asia     |       143 | NULL      |
| Bogart | Bogart   |       389 | Jeff      |
| Greg   | Greg     |       894 | NULL      |
| Hatsy  | Hatsy    |       328 | Jeff      |
| Super  | Super    |       721 | NULL      |
| Goku   | Goku     |       534 | Greg      |
| Banana | Banana   |       520 | NULL      |
| Kyle   | Kyle     |       456 | Banana    |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

This is my current (not working) query:

```
UPDATE members SET parent_id=(SELECT name FROM members WHERE member_id=parent_id);
```

Comment: Are you sure you *need* to do that? Would it not be better to use a JOIN every time you need the parent ID's name?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, using a `UPDATE` with `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE members m1 INNER JOIN members m2 ON m1.parent_id = m2.member_id
  SET m1.parent_id = m2.username
```

Keep in mind that in case the `parent_id` column is a integer / numeric column you can't set the username to this column. You can use a `SELECT` instead of a `UPDATE`:

```
SELECT m1.name, m1.username, m1.member_id, m2.username AS parent_username
FROM members m1 LEFT JOIN members m2 ON m1.parent_id = m2.member_id
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3368e76910d31eaf029560a16a1e8b3)